# USB HID Keyboard emulator

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, low-level, keylogger

I want to make hardware keylogger from my Raspberry Pi model B. I think that I can connect keyboard to raspberry and connect raspberry to computer, but how I can emulate keyboard output?

I consider that here must be some low-level libraries for this purpose, but I can't find someone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement HID device emulator on Pi in order to act like keyboard. But it seems impossible because Pi hasn't separate USB port.

> No, on the Raspberry PI model B the USB hardware is actually connected to a built in Hub, this fixes the USB format as master, there is no way a model B can be a "slave device". Thats said, the SoC of the Raspberry PI is actually capable as being used for both a master and a slave USB device, so theoretically when using a model-A it could be possible to program it to behave as a slave device. Obviously its against the USB specification for a slave device to have a type-A connector, but with some soldering you could connect a type-B or even an USB-on-the-go connector.

[source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=13874)